# Why does ReadFromJsonAsync() method return object properties with null values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly App (ASP.Net Core Hosted, Progressive Web App) with the following logic:

Client:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
    string token = await _loginService.GetToken();

    _http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    var result = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/api/getcalllogs", userCallsRequestFilters);

    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        var morUserCallLogs = await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync < MorUserCallLogsResponse > ();

        await js.InvokeAsync < object > ("TestDataTablesAdd", "#example");
    } else {
        morUserCallLogs = new MorUserCallLogsResponse();
    }
}
```

Server: (Server side API I have the following code which works as expected:)

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MorApiController : ControllerBase
...

[HttpPost("getcalllogs")]
public async Task<MorUserCallLogsResponse> GetCallLogs ([FromBody] MorUserCallsRequestFilters filters)
{
...
return result;
```

Server side controller API populates the model ok and when I inspect I see the following snap (*some values have been blanked out for security)
[image]

Model: (My MorUserCallLogsResponse model looks like this:)

```
namespace MyNumberV2.Model
{
    public class MorUserCallLogsResponse
    {
        public MorUserCallLogsResponse()
        { 
            Calls = new List<MorCall>();
        }
        public string Error { get; set; }
        public bool IsSuccessfull { get; set; }
        public string userid;
        public string username;
        ...
        ...
        public List<MorCall> Calls { get; set; }
        public class MorCall
        {
            public string calldate2;
            public string timezone;
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Back to blazor and when I try to read this returned object on the following line:

```
var morUserCallLogs = await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<MorUserCallLogsResponse>();
```

My retrieved model looks like this:
[image]

As you can see my retrieved model contains all all properties with 140 nested call object models, however all properties are NULL...

Comment: Classic JSON camelCase/PascalCase serialization/deserialization issue

Comment: @aguafrommars Dude, THANKS a TON, I had to make options for the json to be case insensitive, and pass it the ReadFromJsonAsync method `var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() }, PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };`
I also added a converters for enums based on my need.

Comment: It may be better to use `JsonSerializerDefaults.Web` as the starting point: `var options = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web); options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have forgotten to add get; set; for ALL my model properties...

{ get; set; }

```
  public string Error { get; set; }
  public bool IsSuccessfull { get; set; }
  public string userid { get; set; }
  public string username { get; set; }
  .....
```

Comment: OK, fields don't serialize, properties do.

Comment: there is a code snippet in VS for creating auto properties. Type `prop` and hit tab twice. I use that to create new properties.

Comment: Also, setters must be public. One of the reasons I still use Newtonsoft

Comment: My properties are public with { get; set; } and my object is still ending up with default values, so this didn't end up resolving the issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

I had to use following from property annotation
`using System.Text.Json.Serialization`

```
 [JsonPropertyName("access_token")]
 public string AccessToken { get; set; }
```

Comment: Exactly, this should be the accepted answer, thanks 

Answer (score 2):

`"api/api/getcalllogs"` doesn't match `[Route("api/[controller]")]` and `[HttpPost("getcalllogs")]`

As I read it the Url should be `"api/MorApi/getcalllogs"`

But then again, that should produce a 404 or 400

Comment: Correct this was changed by mistake but only on stackoverflow, actual code reads:
var result = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/morapi/getcalllogs", userCallsRequestFilters);

Answer (score 2):

Mine was fixed by passing an options parameter to the `ReadFromJsonAsync` method, which would make the json to be **case insensitive** about the properties in the json, so in your case, it would look like this:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};
var result = await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<MorUserCallLogsResponse>(options);
```